# Apply to 2 job at the same company, inquire about job 1 status and was given status of job 2 instead

Tags: job-search, recruitment

So I applied to 2 role at this company for which I meet the job requirement. I email the recruiter to inquire about my application status of the first job. A few days later, the recruiter sent me an email for the status of the second job instead of the status of the first job that I had inquired. I not sure how they make that mistake. But the email said that my application/resume for the second job has been foward to the hiring manager for review.

Since I inquired about the status of job 1, but was given an update on job 2, should I email the recruiter again and ask for the status of job 1?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: May not be a mistake as much as that's the only information they could get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. That's the most efficient way to get the status update you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t see how that happened. Isn’t it obvious? You gave your name, someone found an application for the name, and returned its status. Which is more than many people get.

The easiest (and only) way to get the status for job 1 is to ask for it, and with your experience now, mention that you have two applications. Or you will get status 2 again, because that obviously gets found first.